# protractor - switch to facebook login screen when testing Oauth2

Tags: testing, oauth-2.0, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I'm trying to write e2e login test to my application which uses oauth2.
when clicking the facbook login- another window opened (the facebook login). I'm trying to enter the credentials there.
I'm currently using

```
browser.driver.switchTo().window();
```

because it is a new window.
I've read that I can get the name of the window by entering 'window.name' in the console.
when doing that I got '_e_02MT'
I have also tried 'window.document.title' and got 'Facebook'
I've tried the different combinations of

```
browser.driver.switchTo().window('_e_02MT');
browser.switchTo().window('Facebook');
browser.driver.switchTo().window('Facebook');
```

and so on
still can't get to that window. I'm getting the error:

```
 NoSuchWindowError: no such window
```

any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a name of the window, you need to provide **a handle**:

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  // switch to the popup
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

  // do stuff with the popup
  // ...

  // go back to the main window
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```

Comment: great solution :)